# Firebase rules not allowing user to write data in android

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is database structure.

[image]

This is database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "shops-product-list": {
        "$uid": {

        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        }
    }
  }
}
```

key for shops-products-list is logged-in user's uid (ignore first key i.e. -1)

Logged user trying to write new data with this logic.

```
private void addShopVariant(String pid, String vid, String mrp, String sellPrice) {
    // Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
    // /posts/$postid simultaneously

    final String uid = getUid();
    String key = pid + "_" + vid;
    //String key = databaseReference.child("shops-product-list").child(uid).push().getKey();

    ShopProductVariant shopProductVariant = new ShopProductVariant(pid, vid, mrp, sellPrice);
    Map<String, Object> shopProductVariantValues = shopProductVariant.toMap();
    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/shops-product-list/" + uid + "/"+ key, shopProductVariantValues);
    //childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    databaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Function works fine if i set rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

But i want only logged-in  user should be able to write, that too only their own data.

what is wrong is above firebase rules?

Comment: From a quick glance it looks like the rules should work. Can you reduce the code back further to only use constant values? For example: what does `getUid()` return? Is that really the signed in user? Also note that `updateChildren()` takes a completion listener, which may tell you more about why the operation failed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you rules are wrong setup:

It should be as the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Note the syntax it's != not !==

Edit:
Instead of validating this on the server you could do that:

```
scoresRef.child("the user id").setValue("your value", withCompletionBlock: { (error:NSError?, snapshot:FIRDatabaseReference) in


})
```

this way you don't have to do it in the rules

Comment: I think its !== only. please check this official doc link. https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html

Comment: I'm actually using this syntax to configure my rules.

Comment: i tried with != also, but still permission denied error

Comment: what do you get if you try to remove this part  "&& auth.uid === $uid"

Comment: In Firebase security rules `==` and `===` are treated the same, as are `!=` and `!==`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, why user is not able to write the data with the rule in my question. Can you please help on this..